# loading order of drivers for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot

hopefully this will help me get an operating system on my wifes new(parts from newegg) computer.

the only not new part(s) are the hard drives as they are sata and still compatible(or at least i hope), video card(not in it currently) dvd-rom(might be +) and case.

the new parts are as follows:

Crucial 16GB (2 x 8GB) 288-Pin DDR4 SDRAM DDR4 2133 (PC4 17000) Desktop Memory Model CT2K8G4DFD8213

GIGABYTE GA-H110M-A (rev. 1.0) LGA 1151 Intel H110 HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 Micro ATX Intel Motherboard

Stallion Series 600-Watt Modular ATX 12V SLI & CrossFire-Ready PSU from Rosewill

Intel Pentium G4500 Skylake Dual-Core 3.5 GHz LGA 1151 65W BX80662G4500 Desktop Processor Intel HD Graphics 530

the old parts

wdc 320gb sata hd
some unknown sata dvdrom(- or + not sure)
a case, that works(not that you absolutly have to have one anyways.)

now onto what the parts are doing as a whole.

i can successfully install windows 7 from a burnt dvd without any issues what-so-ever.

upon first boot, no matter what boot option(safemode, safemode w/net etc.) the ps hangs(doesn't freeze as when 'normal' boot mode is chosen the windows logo will continue to pulse/shift/whatever the animation is.) right after disk.sys(at least thats the last thing successfully loaded when viewing the drivers load in safe mode)

the only things plugged into the motherboard are the cpu(duh) 1 of 2 ram sticks to be sure(it does the same thing with 2 in, though)(but also, duh) the hard drive, and the cd rom. i'm running video off the onboard video which has a default (and only) HDMI output.

i also have a (used)465gtx video card i could have in it but have it out to make sure its not what is causing the issue. i know the card works though, i had it in my wifes previous build (which was an oooooolllllld amd build with 2gb ddr1)

anyone else run across this?

is my gut instinct of the motherboard is F'd?

the hard drive from the old pc i tried to boot once, but it restarts with a bsod trying to load windows because of the hardware mismatch. windows would not recover it when trying to install over it either. 
so on that note, i'm using a different hard drive for test installs, a working WDC drive that was in my DVR security system. 
and yes, i used windows installer to format it when installing the new OS.
it all installs error/crash/hang free.

the only thing that i can discern so far is that this motherboard only supports AHCI for sata controllers, and that i may have an IDE style sata drive?(because its an older drive) i will admit right off that i don't know 100% what i'm talking about, just thinking.

but any thoughts on this would be welcome as my own mind cannot seem to find the answers through thorough google and Stackexchange sites.

i'm uploading a picture of the driver load sequence from booting in safe mode with command propmt, in case the order of things loaded changes with different versions(or updates or whatver) of windows 7 https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNhwT.jpg (i'm curious as to what driver is loaded next, as i assume that it is the culprit of the hang)

i should add that trying to repair the drive from the old system was not successful, windows said it could not.

again, thanks for reading and i appreciate your thoughts on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

First,in the BIOS, there is a setting that switches between AHCI and IDE mode. Have you tried changing that setting? I have had machines work with one setting(usually IDE) and not the other.

Otherwise, to try to determine whether it is a hardware problem, try one of the Linux Live CDs, such as Knoppix. If this works, then you might try actually installing Linux to see what happens. If this works, it tends to eliminate a hardware problem.

Comment: the odd thing about this motherboard, no IDE setting, only selectable thing is AHCI.

Comment: thanks for reminding me about linux... i should have thought to do that.

Answer (score 0):

i have managed to solve the issue, albeit exactly how is unbeknownst to me.

what i DO know i did.

Burned a new Copy of Ubuntu 16.04 using IMGBurn

installed, and booted into the OS fine. took this as a queue that all the hardware is physically alright.

found a new iso for win 7 and burned it using IMGBurn

windows installed, rebooted and loade the OS just fine now.